# horizontally center multiple divs within a div in small devices (xs)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, web-frontend

My page has 3 div(s) within a div. In tablet and desktop screens they look good (center-aligned), but on a very small device such as cellphone the inner div(s) are left aligned (I want them to be horizontally center aligned). I applied text-center, and center-block to the outer div but it does not work. Any suggestion? Here are the html, and css codes.

```css
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
portfolio-caption {
 max-width: 281px;
 background-color: #994ACC;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 border-top: 3px solid #ffffff;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div style="max-width: 281px">
      <a href="#" ">
                        <img src="./x/pilotproject1.jpg " class="img-responsive " style="margin: 0 auto; " alt=" ">
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption text-center ">
                        <strong><h4>Project Name</h4></strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
                <div style="max-width: 281px ">
                    <a href="# "> 
                        <img src="./x/pilotproject2.jpg " class="img-responsive " 
                        style="margin: 0 auto; " alt=" ">
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption text-center ">
                        <strong><h4>Project Name</h4></strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
                <div style="max-width: 281px ">
                    <a href="# " class="pilot-link ">
                        <img src="./x/pilotproject3.jpg " class="img-responsive " 
                         style="margin: 0 auto; " alt=" ">
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption text-center ">
                        <strong><h4>Project Name</h4></strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The reason that I have   is that the width  of the pictures is 281 px, if I do not set the width, the width of the div that comes after the img will be bigger than 281 px which is not something that I want.
[as you can see in this picture, the images are all left-aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fkWm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a class `centered` as a container to center elements (please remove the border `border: 1px solid red;` **it is used to show you the container block** ):

```
.centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 281px !important;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

wrap each element you want to be centered.

Also in your css `portfolio-caption` should be `.portfolio-caption` to select a class.

I moved your in-line style to css class `img-responsive` so you can update your style in one place.

```css
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 281px !important;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

.portfolio-caption {
  width: 281px;
  background-color: #994ACC;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 3px solid #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: right;
}

.centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="centered">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt=" ">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="centered">
      <div class="portfolio-caption text-center ">
        <strong><h4>Project Name</h4></strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="centered">
      <a href="# ">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt=" ">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="centered">
      <div class="portfolio-caption">
        <strong><h4>Project Name</h4></strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="centered">
      <a href="# " class="pilot-link ">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt=" ">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="centered">
      <div class="portfolio-caption text-center ">
        <strong><h4>Project Name</h4></strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel H :)

Comment: @NinaDev happy to help =D

Answer (score 0):

Use 
Text align : center ;

```
text-align:center

<div style="max-width: 281px; text-align : center">
```

Plunker link :

https://plnkr.co/edit/UaW436KiylzfqOCU1cg1?p=preview

Comment: Please check the shared link in answer

Answer (score 0):

You should not apply classes to outer divs, apply them exactly to what you want to be centered : class="img-responsive center-block", and 
also check the bootstrap version center-block is new in Bootstrap version 3.0.1 i believe.